# How do I display all elements of a ViewModel in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I know that you can do @Html.DisplayForModel and ValueForModel, is there anything similar the viewModel? I want to display all the property names and the property values for the elements in my viewmodel

My regualr ValueFor is not working either

Heres what I have so far...although, its not working:

```
@model BookStore.ViewModels.CheckOutViewModel       
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2>Checkout Summary</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Payment Information</legend>

        @Html.ValueFor(m => m.CreditCard1)<br />
        @Html.ValueFor(m => m.CreditCardType1) <br />

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.CreditCard1)
        @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.CreditCard1)
        @Html.
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
        @Html.ValueForModel()
    </fieldset>

}
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Complete(int? id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

Edit: I guess my real question is how to get ANY property from my view model to show its value

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller? It seems like you're not passing the model to the view.

Comment: posted, now that I look at it I kind of see what you mean, but usually arnt the GET methods just return View()?

Comment: its returning just an integer, not the view model you expect,  your return statement should be like return View(your view model object);

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Looking at your controller you are just returning an integer not your model

You could do something like this if you really are new to this:

```
public ActionResult Complete(int? id)
{
    if(int != null && int != 0){ //Makes sure int isn't empty or 0
       var allModelData = dataContext(); //Get all the data in your dataContext
       var myModel = allModelData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id); //This gets the 
                                                            //model that matches the ID
       CheckOutViewModel viewModel = myModel; //Populate it into your viewmodel
       return View(viewModel); //Return your viewmodel
    }
    return View();
}
```

This isn't the most efficient way of doing things but will get you started with some data.

I would also recommend using Model.PropertyName as ValueFor does a simple render which ignores any templates (Equivalent of calling String.Format)

```
        @Model.CreditCard1<br />
        @Model.CreditCardType1 <br />
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt realize that line didnt get copied, the view model is already included :/

Comment: So what is the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an Id of the object (model) to your view instead of the model itself. You should have somthing like this in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Complete(int? id)
{    
     CheckOutViewModel model = GetModel(id);
     return View(model);
}
```

Where GetModel is some function where you retrieve the CheckOutViewModel based on the id.

Comment: What type of logic would we type into get model? Sorry ive never written anything of this type

Comment: Depends on what you're using? Where do you store your data and what do you want to show in the view?

Comment: all the data is stored in an azure database, I initiate that in the dataContext class (DAL); In the view we want to show a summary of the completed order (all the fields in my viewmodel correspond)

Comment: Then you should call your dataContext class to get the data you want to show and put that in your model. Than pass the model to the view.

Comment: Hey FreddieH, do me mind getting on chat MVC for a bit? me and my group are having trouble writing out our question all at once

Comment: Sorry, I can't right now. But if you have more questions, just ask them. Sure there are more people willing to help here.